# how to get inspect code of website instead of HTML source code using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I know that website source code is different from inspect code functionality of the browser. For example if `iframes` are used source code does not contain integrated  `iframe` data where as inspect element in browser shows integrated code of iframe. I checked and tried all the questions and answers for getting inspect code of the website but did not work in extracting integrated code.

One of the solution to extract inspect code is given as shown below

`elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");`

but even this is giving same source code of that respective element.
Is there any way to get inspect element code of a website using selenium. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

i guess, only browsers get the inspected code.